# Graphql with Apollo - refactor queries, return objects are repeating (same fields in diff queries)

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have several queries that have same return types:

```
// Query 1
gql`
        mutation insert_shops_users($shopId: uuid) {
          insert_shops_users(objects: [{ shopId: $shopId }]) {
            affected_rows
            returning {
              Shop {
                id
                users {
                  userId
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
```

```
// Query 2
gql`
        mutation delete_shops_users_by_pk($shopId: uuid!, $userId: String!) {
          delete_shops_users_by_pk(shopId: $shopId, userId: $userId) {
            Shop {
              id
              users {
                userId
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
```

Now, I'd like to extract this part eg under name `ShopUserResult` and use  that in both queries:

#### Extracted under ShopUserResult

```
Shop {
  id
  users {
    userId
  }
}
```

#### Resulting queries

```
// Query 1 - after refactor
gql`
        mutation insert_shops_users($shopId: uuid) {
          insert_shops_users(objects: [{ shopId: $shopId }]) {
            affected_rows
            returning {
             ShopUserResult
            }
          }
        }
      `,
```

```
// Query 2 - after refactor
gql`
        mutation delete_shops_users_by_pk($shopId: uuid!, $userId: String!) {
          delete_shops_users_by_pk(shopId: $shopId, userId: $userId) {
            ShopUserResult
          }
        }
      `,
```

I'm quite new at graphql, any advice on refactoring would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to refactor repeating sets of fields using fragments ([source 1](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/), [source 2](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/variables-aliases-fragments-directives.html#using-fragments)):

#### Query - before

```
gql`
  mutation insert_shops_users($shopId: uuid) {
    insert_shops_users(objects: [{ shopId: $shopId }]) {
      affected_rows
      returning {
        Shop {
          id
          users {
            userId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
      `,
```

#### Query - after using fragments

Fragment

```
const ShopWithUsers = gql`
  fragment ShopWithUsers on shops {
    id
    users {
      userId
    }
  }
`
```

Query

```
gql: gql`
  mutation insert_shops_users($shopId: uuid) {
    insert_shops_users(objects: [{ shopId: $shopId }]) {
      affected_rows
      returning {
        Shop {
          ...ShopWithUsers
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ${ShopWithUsers}
`,
```